# Which programming language to use with Heroku?

Tags: python, ruby, heroku, hosting

Heroku supports Python/Ruby and I believe now or soon Java.

However it was built to run Rails apps in the cloud using active record...

Is Ruby/Rails better supported, more feature complete or stable for Heroku hosted development or is the architecture advanced enough that all offerings are equally weighted?

Comment: "Java" isn't spelt in all upper case.

Comment: Are you asking this question because you have a specific app that you have developed for which you need an answer, or just general wonderment? Because only one of those belongs on stackoverflow.

Comment: I have a marketplace that I have written in Flask / Lucene / Redis and Postgres which I want to put on Heroku, however there is nothing to stop me converting it to Rails3 if that's a better option. (Hosting cost and opportunity overrides choice of programming language) - this thing will hopefully scale so the architecture needs to be robust... may also switch to elastic search which Heroku has in beta

Answer (score 0):

Personally I had some problems with Scala on Heroku, mostly due to outdated sbt plugins. Not sure how Java fairs in that regard. However, if you are looking for a Heroku-like Java environment, you can't do better than [CloudBees](http://www.cloudbees.com/), which is what I'm using for my Scala stuff now. You can get up to 5 apps for free, so maybe have a look at that.